# HTML/jQuery change only part of the URL on refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button in jQuery that redirects the page like this...

```
$('#changeLang').click(function() {
    document.location.href='/' + $('#languages').val();
})
```

which works fine, but it redirects to the /foo when someone clicks it, if  someone is on a deeper URL...

```
/foo/bar/foobar
```

I want it to only change the 'foo' part, so that on a click it will do this...

```
/$('#languages').val()/bar/foobar
```

Comment: I do not think that is a duplicate because I in fact do want to reload the page, just with a section of the URL modified

Comment: Redirect user on `absolute path` then..Like `http://yourdomainname/value/bar/foobar`

Comment: Do you know the old language you are switching from? If so, you can do a string replace

Comment: but this is on a master template which is on every page of my site so it should redirect /foo/bar to /bar/bar, and also redirect /bar/foo to /foo/foo as well. Preserving everything behind the first /x/

Comment: @Bindrid I am changing the whole site language from entries I have in my db so the user selects a dropdown menu and goes from /eng/foo/bar to /fre/foo/bar or from /esp/bar/foo to /zhu/bar/foo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use window.location.pathname and it will give you everything after the domain, split it into an array, change what you need to and glue it back together with a join.

```
$('#changeLang').click(function() {
    var url = window.location.pathname.split('/');
    url[1] = $('#languages').val();
    document.location.href = url.join('/');
});
```

https://jsbin.com/huqijezoxu/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Thanks, that worked. This had crossed my mind, just wondering if there was an easier way